# $f:\text{integrable}\Leftrightarrow |f|:\text{integrable}$ under different interpretations

Tags: real-analysis

I want to summarize the relationship of "$f$ is integrable" and $|f|$ is integrable". I'm not sure I'm correct, so I post this.

1. **(One-variable) Traditional integral:** Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be bounded. Then $f:\text{integrable}\Longleftrightarrow |f|:\text{integrable}$
2. **(One-variable) Improper integral:**
   Let $f:[a,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ or $f:[a,b)\to\Bbb R$. Then $f:\text{integrable}\Longleftarrow |f|:\text{integrable}$
3. **Multiple integral:** Let $E\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be bounded, and let $f:E\to\Bbb R$ be bounded. Then $f:\text{integrable}\Longleftarrow |f|:\text{integrable}$
4. **Multiple improper integral:**
   $f:\text{integrable}\Longleftrightarrow |f|:\text{integrable}$

Comment: I edited your title because it was wholly confusing as it was.

Comment: All the $\Longleftarrow$-s are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the $\Longleftarrow$-s are wrong. If $A\subseteq [0,1]^n$ is a Lebesgue non-measurable set and $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in A\\ -1&\text{if }x\in [0,1]^n\setminus A\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin [0,1]^n\end{cases},$ (and $E$ is whatever) then $\lvert f\rvert$ is integrable by all means, but $f$ never is.

Comment: I haven't learnt Lebesgue integral yet, so I don't know there may be ambiguous when I post this. Can you help me edit my question that clearly refers to the Riemann integrability? Is direct put the adjective "Riemann" in front of enough?

Comment: this also works with riemann integrability. Just change $A$ by $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: then, for example, $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$ when $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and $f(x)=-1$ when $x\in[0,1]\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is not Riemann integrable but $|f|$ is. This extends easily to all other cases

Comment: (Technically, we need not change anything for this to be a valid counterexample for Riemann integrability). However, @eric, Riemann integration requires some kind of regularity that boundedness alone does not quite capture.

Comment: OK I see. Thanks.